# @svgr/plugin-svgo problems when updating to version 7

Tags: javascript, svg, configuration

In my project, I am using  `@svgr/core`, `@svgr/plugin-jsx` and `@svgr/plugin-svgo` plugins.
I was migrating the three of them from version `6.2.0` to `7.0.0`, where the first two work perfectly, but it's when I'm updating `@svgr/plugin-svgo` that it breaks.

This is the config of one of my custom plugins:

`{

```
{
        type: 'perItem',
        name: 'prepareIcon',
        active: true,
        description: 'Prepare the icons',
        fn(item) {
          if (item.isElem('svg')) {
            item.addAttr({
              name: 'fill',
              value: 'currentColor',
              prefix: '',
              local: 'fill',
            });
          } else if (
            item.hasAttr('fill', 'none') ||
            item.hasAttr('fill-opacity', '0') ||
            item.hasAttr('d', 'M0 0h48v48H0z') ||
            item.hasAttr('d', 'M0 0h48v48H0V0z')
          ) {
            return false;
          } else {
            item.removeAttr('fill');
            item.removeAttr('stroke');
            item.removeAttr('stroke-width');
            item.removeAttr('fill-rule');
            item.removeAttr('clip-rule');
          }
          return true;
        },
      },
```

When trying to run my script to generate my application icons, I get the following error in my console item.isElem is not a function

The guide i've been trying to follow is https://github.com/svg/svgo/releases, but am feeling a bit lost

Any type of input would be very appreciated